# How to import API into my Azure API management that is published by another Azure API management portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I want avoid having my API accessed directly by multiple third parties so I am publishing my API through the API management portal but now I am being challenged that third parties that wants to access my API cannot import the API into their portal from my API management Portal, I tried to find documentation about this but found none, so how can I import an API from another Azure API management portal, or rather how can they do that from my API management portal?

Answer (score 0):

If by importing the API, you mean using the API in the Azure API Management Gateway then you can generate the specifications (WSDL, OpenAPI Specification, etc.) of your API and import them in the portal.

Comment: No I mean how can an api from one portal call another api in another petal

Comment: Well, nothing changes there. Like generating any other Http Call. Try using the Send-Request Policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request

Answer (score 0):

Azure APIM's developer portal has a "API definition" link in the top right corner when you're looking at API specification, it will allow one to generate OpenAPI spec or WADL file for an API:

[image]

There is also a REST api to do that by automation if needed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apiexport/get.